# Sudden performance degredation fixed with non-unique index property

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

We are using NServiceBus message queuing service backed by a SQL Server (2016 SP2-CU15) Database.

Yesterday, after functioning without an issue for years, we started to notice server performance degrading and frequent alarms for high CPU.

Looking at running processes (using utilities such as sp_whoIsActive etc), in addition to the expected server load I saw many concurrent delete queries being executed by the NServiceBus service, the majority showing SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits. The server is not-otherwise CPU bottlenecked.

The query being executed in all cases was the following:

```
WITH message AS (
    SELECT TOP(1) * 
    FROM [ServiceBus].[dbo].[Particular.Monitoring] WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK)
    ORDER BY RowVersion
  )
DELETE FROM message
OUTPUT
    deleted.Id,
    deleted.CorrelationId,
    deleted.ReplyToAddress,
    CASE WHEN deleted.Expires IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE CASE WHEN deleted.Expires > GETUTCDATE()
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END
    END,
    deleted.Headers, deleted.Body;
```

The table being deleted from had the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Particular.Monitoring]
(
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CorrelationId] [varchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[ReplyToAddress] [varchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Recoverable] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Expires] [datetime] NULL,
[Headers] [nvarchar] (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Body] [varbinary] (max) NULL,
[RowVersion] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Index_RowVersion] ON [dbo].[Particular.Monitoring] ([RowVersion]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Expires] ON [dbo].[Particular.Monitoring] ([Expires]) INCLUDE ([Id], [RowVersion]) WHERE ([Expires] IS NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Examining the activity on the table, it was receiving between 2-3k inserts per minute, deletes were occuring at between 30-60 per minute, the table was rapidly and unexpectedly growing in size.

Running the above query manually in SSMS the duration was over one second; the execution plan showed an innocent-looking plan with a clustered index scan with number of rows read=1, however IO Statistcs reported 100k logical reads.

I tried suspending the NServiceBus service and deleting rows from the table manually in batches of 4k rows - this worked and all rows were removed in a few seconds and server CPU dropped to normal levels. Restarting the service saw the issue repeat with the table rapidly growing.

I dropped and recreated the existing clustered index to be a *unique* clustered index and this immediately resolved the issue.

Checking the delete query, it was still a clustered index scan showing a single row being read but now with logical reads of 30 and the deletes were keeping up with inserts and the table (once again) never contained more than a handful of rows at any point in time.

So my question is how could this situation have suddenly occured with no changes to either the SQL Server database or NServiceBus application, and why would making the clustered index unique be a solution? I understand this would remove the behind-the-scenes overhead of making the rows unique, but given the index is already clustered, why would the logical reads have suddenly become (presumably) a table scan and why would this have caused so much CPU load?

It should be noted that there are many tables handling messages for numerous end-points and all have the exact same schema ie a non-unique clustered index.

Comment: Do you still have the plan when the problem occurred? You mentioned it was "innocent looking" but the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` waits suggest a not so innocent parallel query, although the SSMS plan could be different.

Comment: @DanGuzman Unfortunately I don't however I will endevour to reproduce - however the plan for the query was certainly not a parallel plan, it *looked* simple, by that I mean visually there was nothing to suggest it was doing a lot of IO, arrows between the operators were 1 pixel etc

Comment: I have reverted the table to a non-unique clustered index and will see if the issue occurs again, although being the weekend I suspect I will have to wait, if it is going to reoccur at all. [this is the current visual plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ujy.png) and during the high CPU load period and with statistics IO showing 1000s logical reads the query plan looked identical - with the exception the execution time for the clustered index scan was about 1.2 seconds instead of 0.

Comment: The unique index is the best definition but I can't explain why you would see `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` waits for a serial query like the visual plan image. I could not coerce a parallel plan using the DDL in your question.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman - indeed I was not seeing a parallel plan (at least executing the query in SSMS) even with rows growing past 100k, yet the performance of each delete was dire until amending the clustered index - from never being an issue until yesterday. I suppose it's also possible just dropping and recreating the index identically may have also fixed it, there's no way I can know.

Comment: Please link your after and your before (once you have it) actual execution plans in your post via [Paste The Plan](https://www.BrentOzar.com/PasteThePlan), there's a lot of information encoded in them that's not visible in a screenshot. The before plan could be helpful if it becomes available. It's possible recreating the index was a factor. For future reference you can also enable the [Query Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) to automatically capture and *log* your execution plans.

Comment: Thanks @J.D.. If I can get the problem to reproduce I'll be sure to attach the plan, I'm familiar with *pastetheplan*; Unfortunately I don't have QS enabled for this database as it's a 3rd-party application and not something that's historically been a problem or required any intervention.

Comment: By recreating the index, you also got fresh statistics at the same time… did you try to update statistics before changing the index?

Comment: @EricPrévost Unfortunately not and I did suspect that might be related. The activity in the database has not changed though and the particular table *normally* only has rows transitioning through it and never has a large number of rows, and after manually deleting all rows even if the statistics were way out, deletes should have been lightning fast even with a table scan since there would have been minimal data pages to read - all presumptions of course.

Comment: And turn on Query Store!  This is probably a bad/poison plan possibly following a recompile triggered by a unusual state of your data.  You need to have Query Store on before this happens again. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15